# Stored Procedure with two raiserrors

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I use SQL Server.

I want to write a stored procedure that looks if a `questionid` and `employeeid` exists (`questionid` is in the table `question`, same for `employeeid`, is in the table `employee`) AND looks if they not already existing in the table (you don't get a duplicate in the table `contentment`). I want raiserror's for the user if so.

In my case it is possible to have a duplicate but not on the same `DATE`!

**Contentment** table has columns:

```
employeeid, questionid, date, score
```

`employeeid`, `questionid`, `date` make up the primary key.

So I want something like this:

```
1,1, 18-11-2018, null
1,1, 19-11-2018, null
```

and not something like this:

```
1,1, 18-11-2018, null
1,1, 18-11-2018, null
```

I already made something but it is not working (1-1-1900 is a standard date, because it is `primary key` it needs to be inserted, `score` is not inserted because the user needs to do this):

```
    @employeeid int,
    @questionid int
as 
begin
    if exists (select * from question where questionid = @questionid)
       and exists (select * from employee where employeeid= @employeeid)
    begin 
        insert into contentment (employeeid, questionid, date, score)
        values (@employeeid, @questionid, '1-1-1900', null)
    end

    if (select count(*) 
        from contentment
        where employeeid = @employeeid 
          and questionid = @questionid 
          and date = date) = 0
        raiserror ('@employeeid or @questionid already existing', 16, 1)    
    else
        raiserror ('@employeeid or @questionid are not existing', 16, 1, null)          
    end
```

Comment: Hi there, tag your database to get proper attention. Different RDBMs have different syntax and even commands

Comment: @JorgeCampos Sorry I forgot to mention, just did.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to date validation you need to provide @date as well. I have created a sample stored procedure with detail that you provide:

```
DROP PROCEDURE P_ContentmentInsert
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE P_ContentmentInsert
    @employeeid int,
    @questionid int,
    @date       DATE
AS
BEGIN
    --Check if exists Employee, Question and Contentment
    DECLARE @IsEmployeeExists       INT=ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM employee WHERE employeeid= @employeeid),0)
    DECLARE @IsQuestionExists       INT=ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM question WHERE questionid = @questionid),0)
    DECLARE @IsContentmentExists    INT=ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM contentment WHERE questionid = @questionid and employeeid= @employeeid and [date]=@date),0)
    DECLARE @ErrorMessage           VARCHAR(1000)=''

    --If one of the validation not passed give error message
    IF (@IsEmployeeExists=0 OR @IsQuestionExists=0 OR @IsContentmentExists=0)
    BEGIN
        IF @IsEmployeeExists=0
                SET @ErrorMessage='-EmployeeId Not exists'
        IF @IsQuestionExists=0
                SET @ErrorMessage=@ErrorMessage+'-QuesitonId Not exists'
        IF @IsContentmentExists=0
                SET @ErrorMessage=@ErrorMessage+'-Contentment already exists'
        RETURN
    END

    --If there is no problem insert it.
    IF @IsEmployeeExists>0 and @IsQuestionExists>0 and @IsContentmentExists>0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO contentment (employeeid, questionid, date, score)
        VALUES (@employeeid, @questionid, @date, null)
    END

END
```

Comment: Why I need to provide date as well then?

Comment: Because you want to validate date as well. You said you have three primary key QuestionId, EmployeeId and Date in contentment table. You need to provide Date to validate it.

Comment: See my example, can I do it that way?

Comment: You'd need to clarify under what circumstances you enter an actual date, because the code you show always uses the same date, and therefore will always cause an error the second time around. You can do the check after the insert, but then you need to rollback the transaction as well. Much better to test first if you can.

Comment: Some more questions: why do you do INT=ISNULL (Select Count(1) ...... )? And @ErrorMessage = @ErrorMessage+ ..... ? Thanks!